# Drawing a funnel with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Does anyone have a method for drawing a funnel in Tikz?

I am attempting to replicate the funnel drawn for this past year's AP Calculus BC free-response questions.

I have attached the image that I would like to recreate using Tikz below.

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Well, what do you have so far and where are you getting stuck? Since you are using a particular drawing package, presumably you have at least a passing familiarity with it. If not, there are plenty of examples to get you started (in the manual, here, on other sites ...). Or you can just use `\includegraphics...` and not worry about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a starting point.  You should be able to adjust this easily by reading the [TikZ manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \sgn in {-,+}
    \draw plot[domain=0:10] ({\sgn 1/20*(3+\x*\x)},\x);
  \foreach \h in {0,5,10}
    \draw (0,\h) ellipse[x radius=1/20*(3+\h*\h),y radius=(\h+.5)/20];
  \draw (0,0) -- node[right] {$h$} (0,5);
  \draw (0,5) -- node[above] {$r$} ({-1/20*(3+5*5)},5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]